# How to decide if the efforts put in corresponds to co-authorship or co-first authorship?

Tags: publications, authorship, author-order

During my PhD, I had 4 first author papers, two co-author papers and one co-first authorship paper. My work is computational, so I have collaborated with experimental groups. My lab colleagues who collaborated with other experimental groups always went for co-first authorship in their papers.

Now, my logic of going for co-authorship or co-first authorship is the following:

If I am doing very straight forward modeling work that won't require developing new models and is based on my previous work, I go for co-authorship. I carry out simulations and write a small methodology and discussion about the results.

However, if my part of the work involves development of new models AND carrying out simulations AND writing up the methodology, discussion of the simulations, I go for co-first authorship.

However, during my postdoc, I have been collaborating with a PhD student. I was involved in development of the important model in the paper. The novelty of the paper lies on the model. The PhD student later incorporated her own PhD work into the model. The development of model took quite some efforts on my part. But I didn't do the final simulations or the interpretation of the results. I just wrote the methodology section related to my model development.

In that case, should I go for co-authorship or co-first authorship? How to decide if my efforts corresponds to the first or latter in this case?

Comment: I don't think I can give you an opinion. It depends a lot on what the model is (and how much development went into it). If it's ten lines of pytorch trained on their data you probably shouldn't be a first author, but if it's some closed form physical model that took a year to work out, you probably should be cofirst author

Comment: Authorship isn't about "effort put in". It is about ideas and insights. And I'm sorry that you are working in a field in which such questions would even arise or require answers. Those fields turn what should be collaboration into competition, making a zero-sum game out of research. Sad.